# DB2: Bi-monthly query for a DB2 report

Tags: db2

I am currently writing a Crystal Report that has a DB2 query as its backend.  I have finished the query but am stuck on the date portion of it.  I am going to be running it twice a month - once on the 16th, and once on the 1st of the next month.  Here's how it should work:

- If I run it on the 16th of the month, it will give me results from the 1st of that same month to the 15th of that month.
- If I run it on the 1st of the next month, it will give me results from the 16th of the previous month to the last day of the previous month.

This comes down a basic bi-monthly report.  I've found plenty of hints to do this in T-SQL, but no efficient ways on how to accomplish this in DB2.  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic to get this to consistently work, taking into account differences in month lengths and such.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 expressions for start and end date of an interval depending on the report date passed, which you may use in your `where` clause.
The logic is as follows:
1) If the report date is the 1-st day of a month, then:
  `DATE_START` is 16-th of the previous month
  `DATE_END` is the last day of the previous month
2) Otherwise:
  `DATE_START` is 1-st of the current month
  `DATE_END` is 15-th of the current month

```
SELECT
  REPORT_DATE
, CASE DAY(REPORT_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN REPORT_DATE - 1 MONTH + 15 ELSE REPORT_DATE - DAY(REPORT_DATE) + 1  END AS DATE_START
, CASE DAY(REPORT_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN REPORT_DATE - 1            ELSE REPORT_DATE - DAY(REPORT_DATE) + 15 END AS DATE_END
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  DATE('2020-02-01')
, DATE('2020-02-05')
, DATE('2020-02-16')
) T (REPORT_DATE);
```

The result is:

```
|REPORT_DATE|DATE_START|DATE_END  |
|-----------|----------|----------|
|2020-02-01 |2020-01-16|2020-01-31|
|2020-02-05 |2020-02-01|2020-02-15|
|2020-02-16 |2020-02-01|2020-02-15|
```

Answer (score 0):

In Db2 (for Unix, Linux and Windows) it could be a  `WHERE` Condition like

```
WHERE
 (CASE WHEN date_part('days', CURRENT date) > 15 THEN yourdatecolum >= this_month(CURRENT date) AND yourdatecolum < this_month(CURRENT date) + 15 days
  ELSE  yourdatecolum > this_month(CURRENT date) - 1 month + 15 DAYS AND yourdatecolum < this_month(CURRENT date)
  END)
```

Check out the [THIS_MONTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061968.html) function - there are multiple ways to do it. Also [DAYS_TO_END_OF_MONTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061473.html) might be helpful